# How can I display the single record from a list of records

Tags: c#, razor, foreach, asp.net-mvc-5, model

> this my model class.  yes my model class have collection properties

1. I want to iterate loop only once when user login and only display the of that loggedin user

> Blockquote

```
    [Table("Booking")]
    public partial class Booking
    {
     [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Booking()
    {
        Cancels = new HashSet<Cancel>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Column("BookingId")]
    [Display(Name = "Booking Id")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Booking Id is required...")]
    public int BookingId { get; set; }

    [Column("BookingStartDateandTime")]
    [Display(Name = "Booking Start Date and Time"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Booking Start Date and Time is reqired...")]
    public DateTime BookingStartDateandTime { get; set; }

    [Column("BookingEndDateandTime")]
    [Display(Name = "Booking End Date and Time"), Required(ErrorMessage = "Booking End Date and Time is reqired...")]
    public DateTime BookingEndDateandTime { get; set; }

    [Column("UserContactNo")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Contact No is required..."), Display(Name = "User Contact No")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserContactNo { get; set; }

    [Column("UserStartingLoaction")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Starting Loaction is required..."), Display(Name = "User Starting Loaction")]
    public string UserStartingLoaction { get; set; }

    [Column("UserDistination")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "User Distination is required..."), Display(Name = "User Distination")]
    public string UserDistination { get; set; }

    [Column("StatusId")]
    [Display(Name = "StatusId")]
    public int? StatusId { get; set; }

    public virtual BookingStatus BookingStatus { get; set; }

    [Column("TaxiId")]
    [Display(Name = "Taxi Name")]
    public int? TaxiId { get; set; }

    public virtual Taxi Taxi { get; set; }

    [Column("UserId")]
    [Display(Name = "User Id")]
    public int? UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserAccount UserAccount { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Cancel> Cancels { get; set; }
}
```

}

1. I Want to display the booking record of that user who is currently loggedIn    not the booking record of all users
2. What can I do with foreach loop to display the loggedin user record

   ```
        if (Session["LoginRole"].ToString() == "User" 
         &&Session["UserId"].ToString() == 
      Model.FirstOrDefault().UserId.ToString())
     {
      <table class="table">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       <tr>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookingStatus.Status)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Taxi.TaxiName)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserAccount.FirstName)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookingStartDateandTime)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BookingEndDateandTime)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserContactNo)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserStartingLoaction)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserDistination)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.BookingId})|
               @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.BookingId }) |
               @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.BookingId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

   </table>
   }
   ```

   this is the controller

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       var bookings = db.Bookings.Include(u => u.UserAccount).Include(t => 
   t.Taxi).Include(s => s.BookingStatus);
       return View(db.Bookings.ToList());
   ```

Comment: You should reconstruct your question to show your datasource... i smell downvotes

Comment: OK, I assume the user has multiple booking records and thus you need the `foreach` versus your details action that would show a single record. I will also assume you have access to the logged in user via Session, identity, etc. So just add a where clause: `var bookings = db.Bookings.Include(u => u.UserAccount).Include(t => 
t.Taxi).Include(s => s.BookingStatus).Where(u => u.UserId == selectedUserId);`.

Comment: @SteveGreene sir,   it still not working now it giving me an exception "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties"

Comment: That means one of the items is a collection and you need a select. Show your model in the question. Also, your view does not seem to make sense. Are you looking to display a single record or a table of multiple records? Your `if` statements checks the first record of the collection, but then proceeds to iterate over the entire collection.

Comment: @SteveGreene yes my model class have collection property and i want to display the record of only loggedin user from the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Index() action is typically used to display a collection. You've got a link to a Details() action which is typically where you display a single record. So you should have a details action:

```
public ActionResult Details(int bookingId)
{
    var booking = db.Bookings
        .Include(u => u.UserAccount)
        .Include(t => t.Taxi)
        .Include(s => s.BookingStatus)
        .Single(b => b.BookingId = bookingId);
    return View(booking);
}
```

Then you would create a Details view similar to this:

```
@model Booking
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Booking Details";
}
<h2>Booking Details</h2>
     <div>
        <dt>Status</dt>
        <dd>
           @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model.BookingStatus.Status)
        </dd>
        <dt>Taxi Name</dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model=> model.Taxi.TaxiName)
        </dd>

        [repeat for other fields]

        </dl>
    </div>
}
```